# Is $Pr(A|B,C)=Pr(A|B)Pr(A|C)$ if $B, C$ are independent?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

My method:

$Pr(A|B,C)=\frac{Pr(A,B,C)}{Pr(B,C)}=\frac{Pr(A,B)Pr(A,C)}{Pr(B)Pr(C)}=Pr(A|B)Pr(A|C)$. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

No.  $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are not necessarily independent when $B$ and $C$ are.

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ with uniform probability distribution.

Let $B=\{1,2,3,4\}, C=\{3,4,5,6\}, A=\{1,2,3\}$ Then ....